# Sails.js : How to return access token after user registration using sails-generate-auth?

Tags: node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js

I am using [sails-generate-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-auth) in my sails.js app. I followed [this](https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/) tutorial to integrate this with my app. When I call `localhost:1337/auth/local/register` it routes to my `callback` action in `AuthController`. My callback action is as follows

```
callback: function (req, res) {
        function tryAgain(err) {
                //some validation
                }
        }

passport.callback(req, res, function (err, user, challenges, statuses) {
            if (err || !user) {
                return tryAgain(challenges);
            }

            req.login(user, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return tryAgain(err);
                }

                //Return the access token created by passport instead of success.
                res.send("Success");
            });
        });
```

I want to replace `res.send("Success");` with the `access token` created by passport. But `User.passport` seems to be null at this point. How do I get the user's `access token` at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The User You Get only contains the data from the 'User Collection' which contains the username email and id. The 'Passport' collection is a seperate collection which contains hashed password, ID, userID(which is equal to the ID In the 'User' Collection) and a token. You need to search in the 'passport' collection for the relavent User. Here is the algoritem:

```
passport.callback(req, res, function (err, user, challenges, statuses) {
  if (err || !user) {
    console.log(err);
    return tryAgain(challenges);
  }

  req.login(user, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return tryAgain(err);
    }

    // Mark the session as authenticated to work with default Sails sessionAuth.js policy
    req.session.authenticated = true

    console.log(user);
    var userID = user.id;
    Passport.find({user: userID}, function(err, items){
        if(err) return err;

        console.log(items[0].accessToken);
        // Make sure you dont give them any sensetive data
        res.json({userData: user, token: items[0].accessToken});
    });
    // Upon successful login, send the user to the homepage were req.user
    //res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

---

Comment: And what if I want to redirect to another view and also send the token?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sails built-in sessions, you do not need to send any token to the client, everything is stored server-side in the sessions and it is tied to the user by the `sid` (session id) cookie, therefore you can redirect to any page.

As long as you have your `sessionAuth` policy it will check that the user is logged-in before accessing your protected routes.

If you would like to use something like Json Web Tokens (JWT) though, sails-generate-auth / sails-auth [do not support it yet](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth/issues/40)